# Message from Pubnub includes file name, decoding does not work (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, pubnub

I'm trying to send JSON data in Pubnub. The docs state that serialisation does not need to be done as Pubnub will do this automatically. My data format is like so:

```
struct CanvasData {
    var previousX: CGFloat
    var previousY: CGFloat
    var currentX: CGFloat
    var currentY: CGFloat
    var isStylus: Bool
    var force: CGFloat
    var radius: CGFloat
}

struct WhiteboardDataModel {
    var points: [CanvasData]
}
```

I send the data using the client like this:

```
client.publish(data, toChannel: "whiteboard-hack", withCompletion: nil)
```

Here `data` is of the type `WhiteboardDataModel`. When I receive the message back on the client I get something like this:

```
Optional(apple_pencil_poc.WhiteboardDataModel(points[apple_pencil_poc.CanvasData(previousX: 717.5, previousY: 378.5, currentX: 717.5, currentY: 378.5, isStylus: true, force: 0.333333333333333, radius: 0.25),apple_pencil_poc.CanvasData(previousX: 717.5, previousY: 378.5, currentX: 717.5, currentY: 378.5, ..etc
```

You can see that the data include the file names of the project and the classes. Why does this happen? How can I decode data like this? Any advice would be really appreciated! thanks!

Comment: What is the PubNub SDK/version you are using? Can you share your PubNub init code (redact your keys for your security but share other values of the params)?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you still need assistance with this issue. If you have a solution already, please post it as answer to your question here.